# Animate circle shortest rotational distance based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, svelte, trigonometry

I'm trying to animate a circle based on mouse position using svelte/motion's tweened function. It doesn't look as seamless as I would like it, naturally, the tweened function has no concept of circular motion and therefore cannot tween the shortest rotational distance. Instead doing a full rotation when  the calculated angle changes to from 179, 180 to -180. -179. My trigonometry knowledge is not great and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction on how to achieve this. A hacky solution I tried was setting the duration to 0 but it's janky and the latency of the mouse remains a problem with quick movements.

```
import { tweened } from "svelte/motion";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const animatedAngle = tweened(0);
    
    onMount(() => {
        const circle = document.querySelector("#animated-circle");

        let circleBoundingRect = circle?.getBoundingClientRect();
        let circleCenter = {
            x: circleBoundingRect?.left + circleBoundingRect?.width / 2,
            y: circleBoundingRect?.top + circleBoundingRect?.height / 2
        };

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
            let angle = Math.round(
                Math.atan2(e.pageX - circleCenter.x, -(e.pageY - circleCenter.y)) *
                    (180 / Math.PI)
            );

            // when tweening between anlges of positive 179, 180 to -180, -179 the animation almost a full rotation
            // ideally, it would be more seamless and rotate the shortest distance
            animatedAngle.set(angle, {
//              duration: 200
                // as you can see 
                
                // below is the best solution I have which is pretty hacky, perceptible and only marginally works when moving the mouse slowly
                duration: 160 < angle || angle < -160 ? 0 : 200
            });
        });
    })
```

Below is a REPL of where I'm at.

https://svelte.dev/repl/2c5a71545ed24401bce3499fe3438f3f?version=3.55.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the last angle, calculate a delta and use that to continually increase or decrease the angle, so you avoid the boundaries at which values would reset. E.g.

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    let angle = Math.round(
        Math.atan2(e.pageX - circleCenter.x, -(e.pageY - circleCenter.y)) *
            (180 / Math.PI)
    );

    // Map to 0-360
    if (angle < 0)
        angle += 360;

    // Modulo 360 to get relative angle in the circle
    const delta = (angle - (lastAngle % 360)) % 360;
    const newAngle = lastAngle + (
                delta < -180 ? delta + 360 :
                delta > 180 ? delta - 360 :
                delta
    );

    animatedAngle.set(newAngle, { duration: 200 });
    lastAngle = newAngle;
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5d10bdf2d3a34b36993d79eb21affdca?version=3.55.1)

Also:

- Do not use `addEventListener` unless you also ensure `removeEventListener` is called `onDestroy`. You can add global events on `<svelte:window>` to not have to worry about cleanup.
- Do not globally query the DOM, either use [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) or `bind:this` to get access to DOM nodes.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for this solution, simple explanations and tips, this is my first svelte project so still learning best practises